# DeSerializing complex json wp7

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I am new to Silverlight and .net architecture. I am working on a Windows Phone 7 project.
where i receive some JSON format data from the server. 
I receive the data from the server ine the callback of webClient interface.
however i am not able to de serialize the data in c# objects.
I am using following code

```
public void GetData_Completed(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result);

        //// Put the byte array into a stream and rewind it to the beginning
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encodedString);
        ms.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;

        // convert json result to model
        Stream stream = ms;
        DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SchedulesResults));
        SchedulesResults myResults =
        (SchedulesResults)dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);

        var result = myResults;
    }
```

the data format that i am supposed to get is like this

```
schedules: [
    {
        id: 2897
        progress: -9
        state: complete
        starts_at: 1315267800
        primary_topic: {
            id: 13
        }
        secondary_topic: {
            id: 9
        }
        scores: [
            {
            schedule_id: 2897
            score: 0
            topic_id: 13
            }
            {
            schedule_id: 2897
            score: 4
            topic_id: 9
            }
        ]
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

and this is the class that i am using to de serilaize

```
public class SchedulesResults
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the results.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The results.</value>
    public Schedules[] results { get; set; }
}

public class Schedules
{
   int id { get; set; }
   int progress { get; set; }
   string state { get; set; }
   DateTime starts_at { get; set; }
   primary_topic primary_topic_ID { get; set; }
   secondry_topic secondary_topic_ID { get; set; }
   Scores[] scores { get; set; }

}
public class primary_topic
{
    int id { get; set; }
}

public class secondry_topic
{
    int id { get; set; }
}

public class Scores
{           
      int schedule_id{ get; set; }
      int score { get; set; }
      int topic_id { get; set; }

}
```

but on de serializing i am getting null in the value.
please tell me where i might be going wrong.

This is the type of data i am getting from server

```
{"schedules":[{"id":3499,"progress":-9,"state":"complete","starts_at":1317945600,"primary_topic":{"id":6},"secondary_topic":{"id":11},"scores":[{"schedule_id":3499,"score":2,"topic_id":6},{"schedule_id":3499,"score":3,"topic_id":11}]},
```

Comment: This might help creating poco's:http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the property in `ScheduleResults` should be `schedules`, not `results`.

---

I mean this:

```
public class SchedulesResults 
{ 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Gets or sets the results. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <value>The results.</value> 
    public Schedules[] results { get; set; } 
}
```

Should be this:

```
public class SchedulesResults 
{ 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Gets or sets the results. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <value>The results.</value> 
    public Schedules[] schedules { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: HI cjk, i am not getting what you mean by "Reports".

Comment: Also to provide more information.. this is the reault that i am getting from server {"schedules":[{"id":3499,"progress":-9,"state":"complete","starts_at":1317945600,"primary_topic":{"id":6},"secondary_topic":{"id":11},"scores":[{"schedule_id":3499,"score":2,"topic_id":6},{"schedule_id":3499,"score":3,"topic_id":11}]},

Comment: @avijeetsingh - cjk meant `results` not `reports`.

Comment: @RichardSzalay i dont understand, "results" is just a name of the Array , i declare "results" or "schedule" its the same the array type will be " Schedules".. does it make any difference in JSON de -serialization.

Comment: The name is very important, imagine you have two String objects.  They can't be desrialized just becase there are strings in the object, it needs to know the names to be able to desrialize properly.  Also, JSON doesn't specify the object type, it is just a collection of names/values that happen to coincide with your object type.

Comment: @avijeetsingh - Yes, unless you specify otherwise using metadata/attributes, the name of the property will be used in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You're appearing to try and deserialize the response as an instance of `MyCLASS` but, (from the code available) it looks like it should be of type `SchedulesResults`.

Comment: My Apology its was Copy paste mistake. i am actually using Scheduleresults. My concern is if i am creating the correct class structure?